# Showing dialog when user loses internet connection in flutter

Tags: flutter, connection

Is it possible to listen to the entire application in flutter and showing the dialog in case of loss of connection?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. The logic is possible however tedious to implement as dismissal of older dialogs becomes an issue. I have however provided you with the codes below. Make sure to use  a `StatefulWidget` and put all this code inside the `initState` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. And you will need one package for this to work.

1. [Internet Connection Checker](https://pub.dev/packages/internet_connection_checker)

You can listen to the stream `onConnectivityChanged` from `InternetConnectionChecker`.

```dart
@override
void initState(){
super.initState();
var isDeviceConnected = false;

var subscription = Connectivity().onConnectivityChanged.listen((ConnectivityResult result) async {
  if(result != ConnectivityResult.none) {
    isDeviceConnected = await InternetConnectionChecker().hasConnection;

    if(!isDeviceConnected){
        showDialog(
           context,
           // Your Dialog Here
    );
    }

  }
});
}
```

Some things to consider here.

1. `showDialog()` needs a context, so put all of this code on the main
   widget with `MaterialApp`.
2. You need to dismiss the dialog by yourself. You wont know if there is a dialog up or not at all. So, do it in your own discretion. Try not to `pop()` the `MaterialApp` itself.